# Can’t See Sql Databases After Creating in VSPM

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I am attempting to create a new database in an existing sql server from code first. I used package manager to enable migrations, add a migration, then update database. The three methods executed without any errors and I got the traditional massages afterwards. However, when I look in either MSSSMS or Server Explorer I don’t see the database. I tried re-running the update database command and got the migration has already been applied. Any suggestions?

Update:
I've figured out that the project is adding the database to localdb. However, I have a connection string in the app.config file.

Comment: How are you determining it isn't there in SSMS? In the object Explorer? Have you refreshed it? In Intelisense? Have you refreshed that? In the `sys.databases` object?

Comment: Yes, all of the above. I refreshed the data connection in ssms as well as closed and reopened twice. I’ve logged into ssms as a different user. In object explorer I established a new connection to the database in VS. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Probable causes are:

- the database was never created
- you use a login that can't see the database. Using Windows authentication/sa might allow you to see it and create user mappings for other logins.
- you have multiple instances of sql running and you're connecting to the default instance while the database what created on a named instance
- you accidentally created the database on another server
- you connect to master by default with your software and instead of creating a database the database structure was created in the system database master

I've been working with MS sql for more than a decade and have struggled with issues like these, but in the end I could always explain what happened; if SQL returns it executed a query succesfully id did.

Comment: 1. Would it be odd that when I try and rerun the update database I would get the message that it’s been applied if the db had not been created?

Comment: 2. I logged in as SA and still do not see the database. How do I check for multiple instances? I don’t see the tables in any other databases including the system databases.

Comment: I will add that the OS of the actual server the sql server sits on was updated recently. Would this cause multiple sql instances? If so how do I connect to the “current” one?

Comment: 2. When you check services.msc the instance name is included in the service name. SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER). MSSQLSERVER is the default instance and other names are named instances you connect to like: [hostname]\[instance name] as server name.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I've never seen that happen. But libraries might act differently.

Comment: 3. Yeah, upgrading SQL usually is done manually and it often happens people accidentally install a second instance instead of upgrading an existing one. When you next > next > next through the setup you fail to update the existing instance and install a second one.

Comment: So I have discovered what is going on, but not why. Apparently, the database is being deployed to localdb not me sqlserver that is specified in the connection string.

Comment: Awsome. I find it a very weird decision from MS to not allow connecting to it with SSMS. I would remove it if I were you!

Comment: I don't quite understand why it keeps using localdb. It may have something to do with my program.cs as I'm in a Blazor app. Trying to use an access layer and model layer as separate libraries.